# Wp8.1 Xaml: list multiple groups of horizontal items in a vertical layout

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am in the process of learning XAML for Windows 8 universal app and have ran into a road block on how to make layout flow the way I want. I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the layout I am looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/2vs6tpzm/

```css
span {
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    line-height:130px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:3px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

h1 {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-size:1.25em;
}
div {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="hub-section">
    <div>
        <div><h1>Heading 1</h1></div>
        <div> 
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <span>Item 2</span>
            <span>Item 3</span>
            <span>Item 4</span>
            <span>Item 5</span>
            <span>Item 6</span>
            <span>Item 7</span>
            <span>Item 8</span>
        </div>
        
        <div><h1>Heading 2</h1></div>
        <div> 
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <span>Item 2</span>
            <span>Item 3</span>
            <span>Item 4</span>
            <span>Item 5</span>
            <span>Item 6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Here is the part of the View Model I am using.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ItemTypeData> ItemTypes { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTypeData
{

    public List<ItemData> Items { get; set; }
    public string ItemTypeName { get; set; }

}

public class ItemData
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my design data

```
<vm:ViewModel
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="using:HubApp1.DataModel">

<vm:ViewModel.ItemTypes>
    <vm:ItemTypeData ItemTypeName="Type 1">
        <vm:ItemTypeData.Items >
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 1"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 2"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 3"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 4"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 5"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 6"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 7"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 8"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 9"/>
        </vm:ItemTypeData.Items>
    </vm:ItemTypeData>
    <vm:ItemTypeData ItemTypeName="Type 2">
        <vm:ItemTypeData.Items >
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 1"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 2"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 3"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 4"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 5"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 6"/>
            <vm:ItemData ItemName="Item 7"/>
        </vm:ItemTypeData.Items>
    </vm:ItemTypeData>
</vm:ViewModel.ItemTypes>
```

Here is my latest attempt at getting this to work with the above information.

```
<HubSection Width="500" x:Uid="SectionTest" Header="Types!">
<DataTemplate>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}" />
                    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Width="150" Height="150" Background="Green">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not believe it :) but this is incredibly convoluted in XAML compared to JS. You do get the benefit of virtualization though.

The most simple solution would be to have a list of lists - e.g. a `ListView` with `ItemsSource` bound to your `ItemTypes` and a stacked header `TextBlock` + `ItemsControl` in its `ItemTemplate/DataTemplate` that has its `ItemsSource` bound to `Items`, its `ItemsPanel/ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `WrapGrid` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` and in turn its `ItemTemplate/DataTemplate` set to a green `Border`. That might be OK for limited lists of `Items` as it wouldn't virtualize these, but if you want to show large (more than 50?) items lists - it might not be good enough.

The better solution then would be to use a [grouped `CollectionViewSource`, `ListView.GroupStyle` etc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh780627.aspx) to get a fully virtualized list, so I'd research that for anything you want to publish.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out grouped CollectionViewSource. For the mean time I have changed my approach to each type group being a separate hub section removing the list within a list problem.